# Let's get rid of these [unexpected-token]s

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[unexpected-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unexpected-token) has 75 questions with no tag wiki and no clear meaning.

Burnination criteria:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It usually refers to a piece of information in an error message, but one that doesn't add any information as to what is actually wrong. It's also used with several languages.

Some times it refers to an error message, other times it refers to the literal meaning (unexpected tokens in an editor or in output). There's also no tag wiki or other usage guidance, and the questions seem to range from Android to PHP, Batch, and even C++, but most dominating, JavaScript.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's a sub-set of programming, but the accurate meaning is, [as a comment mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380948/lets-get-rid-of-these-unexpected-tokens?noredirect=1#comment675351_380948), varied.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Considering the stacktrace in relevant languages cover it, and that it's as ambiguous as it currently is, no, it doesn't.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. As I already mentioned, it refers to errors, rendered output, and even file corruption. Even when it comes to the various errors, they don't mean the same thing in all the languages. There's one question that basically boils down to nested methods not being supported, and others that have missing or misplaced brackets or parentheses.

Comment: "It's a sub-section of programming" it's a subset of a subset of a subset. From the general software developing going down to debugging, to error messages to a specific error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree, because if we burninate this tag we should burninate all such similar "error message tags" consistently. And there are lots!

We have:

- [nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception), 14110 posts.
- [nullreferenceexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullreferenceexception), 2425 posts.
- [segmentation-fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault), 9434 posts.
- [bus-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus-error), 107 posts.
- [syntax-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error), 6814 posts.
- And so on.

All of these fulfil the burnination criteria. All they say is "my program has a bug" and don't add any meaningful information to the question. Error messages should be posted in the question's body.

I agree that these tags, including [unexpected-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unexpected-token) are bad since they are superfluous. Ideally it would be nice to get rid of them. It would be even better if we could get rid of question titles along the lines of "null pointer exception plz halp!".

But it would be a major project/overhaul involving policy changes regarding error message tags, much like the project to get rid of company name tags. It would be a whole lot of work for little gain. These tags aren't actively harmful, they are just superfluous.

If people want to start up such a project, then by all means go for it. But until we have dealt with the bigger picture and have a policy in place, I don't think we should touch any of these tags.

Comment: NPE: `The Java exception [...]`, NRE: `The .NET exception [...]`, segfault: `Use this tag along with a tag indicating the language and a tag indicating the operating system.`, These are all documented *and specific*. Bus error, while wiki-less is [also specific to one type of error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error), but is still specific. unexpected-token has at least 3 current uses (syntax errors in various languages, rendered output, and file encoding issues). [unexpected-token] and [syntax-error] are both too general, while the rest address one specific type of issue

Comment: Burning a single unspecific tag with at least three uses that can be applied to both general computing (SU) as well as any programming language is far from specific, nor does it add much to the post.

Comment: @Zoe Specific? Hardly. See for example [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults). We have lots of posts like that, which have popped up for the purpose of clubbing down questions without any details save for the error provided. All of these error tags are neither specific to a programming language/technology, nor to a tool chain, nor a specific system/OS.

Comment: I'm not sure that "what about all these other bad tags" is a good reason not to burninate a tag. If it was, we'd never burninate anything...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Because we need to set a policy for how to deal with the whole group of tags, and not treat them differently from case to case. Is it even ok to write a title such as "segmentation fault in my program", then tag it with [tag:segmentation-fault]? If not, why isn't the site blocking them. Will the new question wizard be of any help. Should we dupe hammer them to a generic duplicate. Etc. This discussion pops up on meta now and then ([for example see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345510/how-can-we-improve-segmentation-fault-questions)), with no solution.

Comment: Well, I guess if you want to wait for perfect before doing good, I guess that's a way of doing things. Just seems like it could be a long wait, considering how long we've been waiting for a bunch of other changes...

Comment: @HereticMonkey You don't have to wait for anyone, you can bring up the topic of a policy at meta at any time. This is something that the community can handle on its own. But I don't think it solves anything to start burning random error message tags, while at the same time someone sits elsewhere inventing new ones. Because currently these are regarded as valid tags.