# Is there a canonical duplicate for "how do I fix my ArgumentNullException" questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I was reviewing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66839185/10352740) from the "first posts" queue. Since it's asking more or less "How to fix my ArgumentNullException?", I instantly thought this question could be closed as a duplicate because `ArgumentNullException` is more or less always the same problem and fix (just like handling a `NullReferenceException`).

I expected to find something like [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/10352740) (which I use for "How to fix my NullReferenceException?" questions). The issue is, when I started looking for a canonical question to use for my close vote, I couldn't find any. Anything I could find related to `ArgumentNullException` was asking about when they should/shouldn't throw it from their own code.

What question could be used as a canonical duplicate for "How to fix my ArgumentNullException?" questions? And if none, should I write a self-answered question that could become the canonical duplicate? (Surely using the [NullReferenceException question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/10352740) as a template)

Comment: Arguably, the existing NRE question could be used. We already do that for IndexOutOfRangeException/ArgumentOutOfRangeException. As you note, as with the out-of-range scenario, debugging and fixing a null reference is pretty much the same whether the exception is found when trying to dereference is (NRE) or is caught a little earlier by a method validating its arguments (ANE).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm aware about the IndexOutOfRangeException/ArgumentOutOfRangeException question but it's not the same for the NRE question since the NRE question is only about NRE whereas the IOORE/AOORE question explicitly mentions both exceptions, That's why I don't think the NRE question isn't suitable for ANE questions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho that may be the case, but I think this question is just an instance of something more general that should be addressed generally - for other types of errors, and for other programming languages. I have recently been thinking about writing a meta question about it myself, except I couldn't really think how to phrase it (and have generally had a poor experience with meta in the past).

Comment: @nalka: you are right that the title doesn't currently mention ANE. But that question could easily be edited to address both exceptions, just as the IOORE/AOORE question does now. If you are looking for a canonical, why not just polish the existing NRE so that it does work for both? Since the two are practically the same, that would take almost no effort at all.

Comment: That's a typical "I can't debug" question. Unfortunately canonical "How to debug C# programm" won't really fit Q&A format, otherwise I'd be so happy to close hundereds questions a day. Just skip such questions if you don't want to bother with tuned to OP specific problem answer. I like idea of @PeterDuniho to close it as NRE dupe. Btw, `ArgumentNullException` is not that common, mostly users are able to read msdn or again, they can't do this either yet, give them a hint pointing to msdn then, don't bother with the answer. Future reader will NOT benefit from this questions at all.

Comment: "And if none..." Simply make the question you found now the one. There is always a  slight chance that a question you encounter is the first one of its kind.

Comment: @Trilarion I think having a really complete Q&A like the NullReferenceException question as the canonical duplicate would be better.

Comment: I'd probably opt for just incorporating `ArgumentNullException` into the `NullReferenceException` post, which presumably mostly means editing the title to include it and adding a note about it in the answer. Or post a short Q&A which mostly just says one of the arguments of something is null and refers to the NRE post for the possible causes of that. This assumes questions about the error are common enough for a canonical post. I wouldn't duplicate what's written in the NRE post into a separate Q&A. That would mean almost any change required on one needs to be applied to the other as well.

Comment: @Sinatr Questions where the problem is a lack of debugging should be closed with the "needs debugging details" reason. Although I do also think a canonical (probably language-agnostic) post on debugging could be useful, just to establish the basic ideas of setting breakpoints, watching variables, different types of steps and whatever else, and what the use case for each might be (there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), but it seems a bit too vague to be helpful).

Comment: _"using the NullReferenceException question as a template"_ -- that would make no sense. The reason the NRE question works as a template is that the questions are _essentially the same_. Just use the NRE question. If you are concerned that it doesn't name ARE by name, it would be trivial to edit the NRE question to do so, without changing the fundamental advice at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This all seems like lazy moderating to me. `NullReferenceException` could be anything, it's just in the title because the person who asked the question doesn't know how to ask a good question. The actual problem isn't the exception (or the seg fault etc) - it's just a symptom. The actual problem is the bug somewhere in their code.

The correct way of moderating that isn't to clobber the post with some super-broad FAQ listing all manner of different, unrelated possible causes. Just because you are sick of seing "NullReferenceException plz halp" titles.

Yes it would be nice if we could just ban sloppy titles like that from appearing, I even proposed [something like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345510/how-can-we-improve-segmentation-fault-questions) at one point (for the C and C++ equivalent of a nonsensical, generic error: "seg fault").

The correct way would rather be to ask the poster for clarification or close as unclear, if it is unclear. Edit their question title to something meaningful, since NullReferenceException is unhelpful.

It's just as if someone would go to the mechanic and asks "my car is broken what could be the problem" and the mechanic responds by giving you a list of all common problems in cars. Rather, the mechanic would have to patiently probe for more information:

> "My car is broken please help."
> "Does it start?"
> "Yes."
> "Okay, then what is the actual problem?"
> "There's a strange noise when I drive on the highway."
> "Okay so the problem is that there's a strange noise when you drive on the highway, not 'the car is broken'. What brand and model is it-..."

Alternatively, since this is a volunteer site, we don't have to do any of that. We can just down vote and move on. We don't have to moderate every single bad post unless we want to.

But if we chose to do and then just clobber the post as a dupe to some broad super FAQ, I think it is borderline privilege abuse of close votes. That super FAQ is almost certainly not a duplicate of the very specific bug the question asked about.

Comment: Lazy moderating stems from lazy users who don't bother to learn the basics of programming, or read any documentation, or even do a Google search on the error message they're encountering, before vomiting that error onto Stack Overflow. If you want to hand-hold and mollycoddle those users, don't let us stop you - but equally, don't expect the rest of us to be willing to do the same. We're here to teach people to fish, not to stuff fish down their greedy gullets.

Comment: @IanKemp As I said, "We can just down vote and move on. We don't have to moderate every single bad post unless we want to." Apart from that, you are preaching to the choir. I'd love if we could re-introduce close reasons such as "the poster must actually understand the basics of the topic they are asking about" or if we could turn SO back into a site for professional or enthusiasts programmers - a programmer being a person who knows at least the basics of a programming language. But the owners of the site have made it clear that the site should be quantity over quality, so we can't have that.

Comment: @IanKemp I don't think we are handholding, but we aren't doing things better just by closing as duplicate. Maybe it is time that gold badges can unilaterally close questions as unclear.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I agree. It's actually a far more qualified task to close a question as dupe than to close as unclear or too broad. So if someone can be trusted with the former, then why not with all of them.

Comment: The analogy is missing the fact that people show up on at the garage without the car to begin with - beside that they are often missing a drivers license and only read somewhere how cars are operated or what sounds are supposed to happen.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Or their "car" is a scooter. Or a truck. Or doesn't exist. Or is on fire.

Comment: @Braiam I don't understand, what is "unclear" about that question? The OP received a particular exception and they are asking how to fix it; that's about as clear as it gets. If you want to argue that that having a RTFM dupe-target is unhelpful, I think that's a valid viewpoint and probably deserves a Meta discussion of its own (hint hint).

Comment: @IanKemp I'm not talking about any question in particular, but any error should include the way of reproduction. Your example doesn't include that, nor seems the proposed target. That's unclear about them.

Answer (score 11):

Over the years I kinda grew against closing questions as those very generic "canonical" Q&As with dozens of different causes, because of the sheer length and uselessness that accumulates over time in such canonicals.

I mean look at it. No really, look at it. Look at the first answer of the [NullReferenceException canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). It's a sixteen page long answer (at least on my 1080p laptop) that has been edited 57 times in 10 years, chock full of examples and edge cases nobody is ever going to read.

After it, there's a nineteen page long answer that basically states all the same things, except for VB.NET.

Seriously, look at it.

> [image: wat]

Try reading it as someone who just started programming, got an error, mustered the courage to post a question here and got their question dupehammered within seconds or minutes, probably even without a comment explaining why or how it's relevant.

It starts by using 50% of my screen estate with an example full of `unreadable` `inline` `code` that ends with *"... syke, nullable value types don't throw a NullReferenceException, this entire paragraph you just read is irrelevant"*. In fact, those two numbered blurb shows why developers *do* want to use null values, while the answer is meant to teach people how to prevent a NullReferenceException, so the reader most likely *doesn't* want to use a null value.

What follows are a simplification of the exception and some debugging hints, written by yours truly, and not edited in over six years, apart from `adding` **markup** *abuse* (and irrelevant text).

All this Q&A does is show that collaborative editing doesn't work without strict editing guidelines, something Wikipedia figured out two decades ago. The last edit, which coincidendtally was made by you, OP, changed the [correct term "null dereference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_dereferencing) to "NullReferenceException" and made sure `null` is marked as inline code *frigging everywhere* - [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4660186/58) was not a good one.

Does that answer, after all these edits, help these people, some of the most recent victims of this canonical?

- [Asp.net mvc sql membership template throws exception in Visual Studio 2019 when it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873107/asp-net-mvc-sql-membership-template-throws-exception-in-visual-studio-2019-when) - They're not clueless beginners who don't know how to debug, they're specifically asking why the VS 2019 project template throws this exception out of the box. They even show in their question they know how to circumvent the error, namely by initializing the model.
- [How do I fix this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868778/how-do-i-fix-this-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error) - Unfortunately, they responded to the "Does this answer your question?" comment that they don't get it. Too bad, they only read until the "Array" heading on page 3 and failed to scroll down to "Array element" on page 4. Perhaps they got tired of all the markup abuse and irrelevant text.
- [Why I get System.NullRefrenceException in Asp.net Core API Back End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862988/why-i-get-system-nullrefrenceexception-in-asp-net-core-api-back-end) - An IFormFile being null in ASP.NET Core is 9 out of 10 times being caused by the upload code not properly uploading a file as a form post, or the form file name not matching the IFormFile parameter or property name in the action method or its model. Guess what: none of that is addressed in the duplicate, and there are [over two thousand Google hits for "asp.net core iformfile null" on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+iformfile+null+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Surely there's a better dupe?

I don't even want to continue finding examples where it's a totally inappropriate duplicate. People, it is not the short and to the point canonical it once was, and there's new ways of throwing NREs emerging every other week, usually by a combination of factors that cannot easily be debugged, not even after reading seven pages of by far not exhaustive examples.

So yeah, no. Stop using this monstrosity as a duplicate target, and find, edit and use more specific duplicate targets that actually resemble the OP's problem whose question you're trying to close as fast as you can, just because they happened to ask something you saw once too often.

And, on-topic, definitely don't use it for an exception that is not a NullReferenceException, because in that case you're definitely "RTFM"-ing or "LMGTFY"-ing by saying "go learn to debug, bye". That makes you a jerk, and a lazy one at that.

Comment: I agree the NRE post is really lengthy already (and that's one of the reasons I don't want to add ANE stuff to it). About my edit to the NRE answer : the `null` formatting was just a matter of consistency, maybe adding the formatting was the wrong choice and removing it everywhere was the good option. Replacing "null dereference" with `NullReferenceException`, quoting your answer : "the answer is meant to teach people how to prevent a NullReferenceException" so talking about `NullReferenceException` instead of "null dereference exception" serves this purpose.

Comment: About the bad closures now, considering the canonical duplicate for it would exist, I don't mean to close everything that mentions `ArgumentNullException` as a duplicate of the canonical but if the question is more or less "Why do I have this ArgumentNullException?" well it's a duplicate of the canonical. Maybe the canonical won't answer his **true question** "Why is _some stuff_ null?" but as long as the question doesn't get edited to reflect this it should remain closed as a duplicate of the canonical.

Comment: Look, I have seen and made quite a few edits in my time here, and I have quite some experience in writing posts. I can objectively tell you that your edit was a bad one, period. The fact that a long answer talks about a specific exception called a NullReferenceException, does not mean that that answer cannot contain any synonym or proper English declaration of the _source_ of that exception, which _is_ called "dereferencing a null pointer". Conversely; do you really mean that an answer that talks about an ArgumentNullException may not contain the explanation that an "argument is null"?

Comment: And having a post full of `inline code` does not make it any more readable, quite the contrary. Try reading a Meta post or two on the subject.

Comment: As for the canonical you are proposing: yeah duh-doy, an ArgumentNullException is thrown when an argument to a function is null. It has about zero value to create a Q&A that explains that. The interesting part of a question about an ArgumentNullException is the code that causes something to unexpectedly become null, and there does not exist a "one size fits all" duplicate that will answer each and every current and future question about said exception. If it's a typo, it should be closed as such. If it's a non-MRE, it should be closed as such. And so on.

Comment: You've been quoted in [Are canonical dupes a waste of everyone's time?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406363/are-canonical-dupes-a-waste-of-everyones-time)

Answer (score 6):

No, and there doesn't need to be.

An `ArgumentNullException` is a special case of a `NullReferenceException`. Therefore, editing the canonical "What is an NRE" question to add references to ANE where appropriate is the best course of action. We don't need separate canonicals for every conceivable exception type, especially when (as in this case) those canonicals would be almost identical.

Comment: I don't agree that `ArgumentNullException` is a special case of `NullReferenceException`.  An NRE thrown from a class library generally means there is a bug in the class library: it has assumed incorrectly that a reference it is using is not null.  An ArgumentException generally means the *caller* has passed an invalid value (null in the case of ArgumentNullException), and that the class library is probably behaving correctly: one protection against NRE is to validate parameters and throw an ArgumentNullException if an unexpected null is passed.

Comment: This NRE question is getting unwieldy large, too large that it becomes a RTFM question. It doesn't help reducing these kind of questions even in the NRE category, it would be even less effective doin so with ANE.

Comment: I agree on the actual solution "there doesn't need to be", though I don't agree on the rationale (same as Joe's comment).

Comment: @Joe I'm willing to guarantee that 99.999999% of SO questions about NREs and ANEs are due to the caller not checking what they're passing, **not** due to a bug in a library they're using. As such, the only difference is how the library behaves (i.e. which exception type it throws); the **root cause** is the same, ergo the steps to fix it are the same, ergo the canonical can be almost identical.

Comment: @IanKemp - I disagree: a class library that validates parameters and throws ANE (or more generally AE) is following the Framework design guidelines (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/parameter-design#validating-arguments).   And attempting to dereference a null object reference (whether passed as a parameter or generated internally) is a coding error.